# How to move value from the stack to ST(0)?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86

I am having trouble believing the following code is the most efficient way to move a value from the stack to ST(0):

```
.data
var dd 4.2
tmp dd ?

.code
mov EAX, var
push EAX
; top of stack now contains a value

; move it to ST(0)
pop EAX
mov tmp, EAX
fld tmp
```

Is the temporary variable really necessary? Further, is there an easier way to get a value from the stack to ST(0)?

**Update:** In the example above, I'm moving *floating-point* values around - not integers.

Comment: ... but now that x87 is deprecated in x86-64, this is mainly historical information...

Comment: @Art: I'm writing a compiler, so having it generate x86/7 code is hard enough. We'll worry about x86-64 later.

Comment: 7Basic I presume? Sounds fun :)

Comment: @Art: Boy, you really do your research. How'd you figure it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fld dword ptr [esp]    ; assembles to D9 04 24
```

Comment: Uh... your code is calling `fild` which loads an integer value. I need `fld` which loads a floating point value.

Comment: @I. J. From reading the documentation for `fld`, I wasn't aware that that particular addressing mode was available for the instruction. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Note that you still have to increase esp by the relevant size to get proper pop behavior.

Comment: You can use any of the x86 memory addressing modes.

Comment: Like @Nathan said, if you want to duplicate the behavior of your sample code (which did a POP EAX), you'll need to add 4 to ESP.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying - I left a value on the stack. Ya, the code was just an example.